# Steam Market still unavailable after specified date

Tags: steam, steam-community-market

I recently build a PC and installed steam with my usual steam login. Weeks later I get into CS: GO and wanted to sell a case but it says the market is unavailable. What it says right now:

```
The Market is unavailable for the following reason(s):
-You are logging into The Market from a device that has not been protected by Steam Guard for 7 days.
If nothing further occurs to restrict your access, you'll be able to use The Community Market on 1/26/2015 10:48:53 PM.
```

I checked my profile and it says Security Status: Protected by Steam Guard

Now that its the 27th I still can't use the market, is there something else I need to do?

Comment: I wonder if it is a time zone issue?

Comment: i'm EST, maybe I need to buy something on this new PC?

Comment: I'm in EST in Canada and it isn't past the time your quote shows (its 8:29 pm on the 26th) so....I think I might have found your problem?

Answer (score 2):

> The Market is unavailable for the following reason(s):
>   -You are logging into The Market from a device that has not been protected by Steam Guard for 7 days.
>   If nothing further occurs to restrict your access, you'll be able to use The Community Market on 1/26/2015 10:48:53 PM.

Steam Guard is a feature set in stone to prevent people from gaining access to your steam account and trading everything to themselves, this was a huge problem in TF2 some time ago.

For example, if you log in to your account at a friends house and forget to close steam, he essentially can't steal your stuff.

The way this timer works is the exact time you re-activated steam onto a new machine, and you must wait exactly 168 hours until you can trade or use the market again.